# Dom rendering issues ngAfterViewInit ionic 2

Tags: angular, dom, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic and angular. I notice some peculiar issues.

Whenever I need to access the DOM i have to do a time out query to get dynamic elements.

event if I use ngAfterViewInit - this doesn't work.

So for example when trying to access a dynamically generated url this wont work.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {

    var that  = this;
    that.img = that.el.nativeElement.querySelector('img');
    alert(that.src);

}
```

However this will

```
 ngOnInit() {

      var that  = this;
      setTimeout(function () {  // still buggy need to wait for dom to load.

      that.img = that.el.nativeElement.querySelector('img');

      alert(that.src);

      }, 300);
    }
```

I am using ios emulator this is in an Ionic component I have tried the following code which doesn't work without a time out. Because the url which is generated by javascript in the view doesn't get registered without the Dom loading fully.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

    import ImgCache from 'imgcache.js';

    /**
     * This component will be in charge of caching images and use them when the app is offline
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'lazy-img',
      template: `
        <div [ngClass]="{ 'placeholder': hidden }">
          <img [ngClass]="{ 'active': !hidden }" [src]="src" (load)="load()" (error)="error()" />
        </div>
      `
    })
    export class LazyImgComponent implements AfterContentInit {

      @Input() src: string;

      public img: HTMLImageElement;
      public hidden: boolean;

      constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
        this.hidden = true;
      };

      ngAfterContentInit() {

        var that  = this;

        that.img = that.el.nativeElement.querySelector('img');
        that.img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

        // check if the images are already cached
        ImgCache.isCached(that.src, (path: string, success: boolean) => {

          if (success) {
            alert('cache ' + that.src);
            ImgCache.useCachedFile(that.img, function (){
                alert('now using local copy');
              }, function(){
                alert('could not load from cache');  // desnt work with live reload
              })

          } else {
            alert('no cache ' + that.src)
            ImgCache.useOnlineFile(that.img);
            ImgCache.cacheFile(that.src, () => { });


          }

        });
      }



      /**
       * This function will show the image when it has loaded
       */
      load(): void {
        this.hidden = false;
      }

      /**
       * This function will be triggered when http request fails
       */
      error(): void {
        this.img.remove();
      }

    }
```

Comment: i am not quite sure but please take a look at this link hope it helps https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ionViewDidLoad()` event.

*ionViewDidLoad()*

> Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page
>   being created. If a page leaves but is cached, then this event will
>   not fire again on a subsequent viewing. The ionViewDidLoad event is
>   good place to put your setup code for the page.

Another event is `ionViewDidEnter()`

*ionViewDidEnter()*

> Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This
>   event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

Here is the [**official doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: I am using in a component and not a page - ionViewDidLoad doesn't get called there and I think is for pages only.

Comment: what did you mean by component here? if you use Ionic2 then a page is also a component.

Comment: if you need to access dom elements then why can't you use the page?

Comment: I could but I want to access it in a component so it is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Is the dynamically generated content created upon initialization? Or is it dependent on some observable pattern where the URL may not appear until after initialization fully occurs?

Another lifecycle hook you can try is `ngAfterContentInit()`

> Respond after Angular projects external content into the component's
>   view.
>
> Called once after the first ngDoCheck().
>
> A component-only hook.

Comment: @michaelcoyne Angular2 docs specify this function is called only _once_, you're sure you get multiple calls when using this? Maybe you had other lifecycle hooks enabled at the time too?

Comment: Sorry you are correct this was a different one. It still doesn't work and I have to put the time out on.

Comment: @michaelcoyne how is your dynamic content that's causing the issue generated then? Is it rendered to the DOM immediately after the component is initialized? Or is it dependent on a service returning data first before rendering?